# Regex for replacing a single-quote with two single-quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm running into an issue that I think is being caused by needing to double-up on some single quotes inside a string. However, JS's string.replace uses RegEx, and I've never built a RegEx by hand.

Can someone help me build a RegEx to find a single quote and replace it with two single quotes?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try this:

```
yourstring = yourstring.replace(/'/g, "''")
```

Comment: @YumYumYum, in that case you don't need "replace a single-quote with two single-quotes", but to encode that additional apostrophes.

Comment: How do you do that what you just mentioned please? I have tried my way but failed, i need to have single quote and double quotes as it is for display and submit.

Comment: @YumYumYum, ask a new question!

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use RegExp.

String patterm version:

```
str.replace("'", "''", 'g')
```

RegExp pattern version:

```
str.replace(/'/g, "''")
```

Here you have some useful RegExp links:

- [RegExp Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html)
- [Regular Expression Basic Syntax Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)
- [RegExp Build&Testing Online Tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Answer (score 5):

`str.replace(/'/g, "''");`

Be sure to use the global match flag (g) so that you replace any and all occurrences in the string.
More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: That makes a double quote from a single quote, but does not replace a single quote by two single quotes, as the OP asks.

Answer (score 4):

> JS's string.replace uses RegEx

Not necessarily:

```
var str = "O'Reilly's books";
alert(str.replace("'", "''", 'g'));
```

[MDC's String replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) reference:

> The pattern can be a string or a RegExp

Mmm, my code above doesn't seem to work on IE6, so that will be:

```
str.replace(/'/g, "''")
```

like the others said, but using regexes for such simple operation is overkill.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function QuoteEncoding(strvalue) {
    var strquotes = /(')/g;
    return "'" + strvalue.replace(strquotes, "''") + "'";
}
```

call this method as follows:

```
QuoteEncoding(strvalue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you don't want to use RegExp (and there are often good reasons not to), the idiom for a simple string replacement is:

```
str.split("'").join("''")
```

Although the RegExp version is typically marginally faster, the string version can be a win when you don't know if there might be regex-special characters (like `.`) in the search string.

Comment: I was using IE7 and was wondering why all of the answers above this weren't working.  Once I implemented this str.split().join() all of my apostrophes were replaced correctly.  For whatever reason the "g" was being ignored.  Thanks bobince to sharing fundamentals!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact syntax, but you can find that out yourself:

```
str.replace(/(?!')'(?!')/g, "''");
```

Haven't tested this yet, but if it works, it also takes care of only replacing occurances of **one** single quote in a row. The g modifier is necessary for replacing all ocurrences.

Comment: this does not work.  But, I really want it too because I like the idea behind the idempotentness of this tranlation

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070275/regular-expression-match-only-non-repeated-occurrence-of-a-character

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String#replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll).

```js
const str = "'test'";
const replaced = str.replaceAll("'", "''");
console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: Simple, yet powerful! Based on my limited knowledge of JavaScript, it looks like `replace` and `replaceAll` functions in JavaScript behave exactly in the opposite manner as they do in Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
js> s = "abc'def'xyz"
abc'def'xyz
js> s.replace(/'/g, "''")
abc''def''xyz
```