# How to convert upper to lower and replace spaces with dashes?

Tags: javascript, regex, xhtml

I want to convert good bunch of url text.

from

```
CUSTOMER FAQS
HOW wE can HELP
PLANNING YOUR BUDGET
CUSTOMER CASE STUDIES
TENANT DISPUTES
EXIT STRATEGIES
USEFUL dOCUMENTS
USEFUL lINKS
```

to

```
customer-faqs
how-we-can-help
planning-your-budget
customer-case-studies
tenant-disputes
exit-strategies
useful-documents
useful-links
```

Is there any online or offline tool which can do this?

I want to do both thing at once.

Comment: I like this line *"Don't be afraid to ask for help. It shows strength, not weakness"*... :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
value = value.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'-');
```

- toLowerCase -> convert this string to all lower case
- replace(/ /g,'-') -> Globally replace (/g) all spaces (/ /) with the string -

See also:

- [Convert JavaScript String to be all lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154862/convert-javascript-string-to-be-all-lower-case)
- [Regex for replacing a single-quote with two single-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609947/regex-for-replacing-a-single-quote-with-two-single-quotes)

---

If you just want to have this functionality and use it locally in your browser, you can make yourself a simple html page and save it to your desktop as convert.html (or whatever).  However if you're going to go that far, I'd just use a shell script/command as one of the other answers posted.

```
<html>
<body>

    <h2>Input</h2>
    <textarea id="input"></textarea>
    <button onClick="doConvert()">Convert</button>

    <hr/>
    <h2>Output</h2>
    <textarea id="output"></textarea>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doConvert() {
            var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
            var newValue = value.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'-');
            document.getElementById('output').value = newValue;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can i give me explanation how can i use this code with any online or offline tool

Comment: @T.stone thx for info I've seen links but still idon;t know how to use. can u give me any link step by step link. I don't know javascript hardcore programming and regex

Comment: This is getting close to me doing everything so I'm going to stop.  The functionality you're asking about is commonly referred to as right trimming.  Try googling it (http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS348US349&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=right+trim+javascript)

Answer (score 6):

```
YOURTEXT.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,"-")
```

Comment: Ah no problem, I think you did that, I just got a claim :P

Answer (score 2):

The `tr` command can do this:

```
$ tr 'A-Z ' 'a-z-'
CUSTOMER FAQS
customer-faqs
HOW wE can HELP
how-we-can-help
```

Comment: `tr` is a Unix command line command. You asked for an "online or offline" tool, so `tr` is offline.

Comment: I'm using Windows XP and i have dreamweaver installed , now pls tell me how can i use your code. i've this also http://www.waterproof.fr/products/RegExpEditor/

Comment: If you're running Windows and you want to use `tr`, install Cygwin: http://cygwin.com

Comment: I think installing Cygwin is a bit of overkill for this requirement.