# Regular Expression: match only non-repeated occurrence of a character

Tags: regex

I need to find and replace all occurrences of apostrophe character in a string, but only if this apostrophe is not followed by another apostrophe.

That is

> abc'def

is a match but

> abc''def

is NOT a match.

I've already composed a working pattern -  `(^|[^'])'($|[^'])` but I believe it may be shorter and simpler.

Thanks,

Valery

Comment: like this?? http://rubular.com/r/5oHGVS3r1c

Comment: What environment is this? Perl? Javascript? PHP? Java? POSIX? Not all regex syntaxes are the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

depends on your environment - if your environment supports lookahead and lookbehind, you can do this: `(?<!')'(?!')`

Ref: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 2):

I think your pattern is short and precise. You could be using negative lookahead/lookbehind, but they would make it a lot more complex. Maintainability is important.

Comment: ye, I've been using regexp for years and only took the time to understand lookahead and lookbehind yesterday, because of a stackoverflow question. Probably says more about me than the feature, but bottom line is that the original version is clear even when you have a more basic knowledge of regexp, and is consistent across all environments.

Comment: @Tao: That is exactly what i am talking about :)

Comment: Totally agree, while lookahead/lookbehind example above is nice, short and correct, my own primitive version is easier to understand for non regex savvy developers. Still in doubt which approach to use :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to be careful for an uneven number of apostrophes:

```
abc'''def
```

where you probably *do* want to replace the 3<sup>rd</sup> one and leave the 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> in there.

You can do that like this (assuming you already matched string literals and only want to replace the uneven numbered trailing apostrophe):

Search for the pattern:

```
(('')*)'
```

and replace it with

```
$1
```

which is group 1: the even numbered apostrophes (or no apostrophes at all).

I'm not sure what actual problem you're solving, but in case you're parsing/reading a CSV file, or a string that has the likes of CSV input, I highly recommend using a decent CSV parser. Almost all languages have them in some form or another.

Comment: No, this is not CSV. Actually I was solving an issue with Java class MessageFormat that swallows single apostrophe character.

Answer (score 0):

see here nagative lookahed `q(?!u)`

- `(?=pattern)` is a positive look-ahead  assertion
- `(?!pattern)` is a negative look-ahead assertion
- `(?<=pattern)` is a positive look-behind assertion
- `(?<!pattern)` is a negative look-behind assertion

#### http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

### [working DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/5oHGVS3r1c)