# NodeJS: Sanitize quotes in string for mssql

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I have a string that contains single quotes, it needs to be used in a simple insert query to a SQL Server database, I understand that to sanitise quotes I need to have them in this format:

```
''
```

However any library or piece of code I find tries to sanitize my quotes with

```
\
```

Does anyone know any good library or function to achieve this?

Here is an example of a string I am trying to sanitise:

```
{\"encSeed\":{\"encStr\":\"dPF5tHXybDYbo00X9/gb0HCPkhPr4V9K6bhtfT5/XNvpWVLIsa4wpcwkKQaqIWLwcU3IslwsyHBRTXqk2F4h/ah0hYBzQ25d8d/XRlaDIp7BrisdjNS/rKIDOdAT7dH7JonQM7Z62eRdWoMjdoYlV8SSjve+MXPO1FTg7f+B5Sj4XarCM3H/qA==\",\"nonce\":\"jiNgWhQ1zPLVHAF9aM/A2sHgmSVG7d7S\"},\"ksData\":{\"m/0\'/0\'/0\'\":{\"info\":{\"curve\":\"secp256k1\",\"purpose\":\"sign\"},\"encHdPathPriv\":{\"encStr\":\"YdW69l49UH02JIa8jc9npFbFNcn9TrXBG6Umwms0BlB0dW/AkQwpbcgS7KQ/z8sTXTDsG9pBtSh/0KqrthrQ590fLEcOREz/VSzZ6mzc292TWZLYYMW4uGqZbbl/HaTFUAoSyB03A6xCs4mtARcQxsf0XxFVwaweOMStgPlhEA==\",\"nonce\":\"QvtCcI6cWdfevcFbxT8Xzae+CxGpBH9W\"},\"hdIndex\":1,\"encPrivKeys\":{\"4eaec019c6f1b6806426767b146bcbb4966d3608\":{\"key\":\"F2KrrLZhRjWs2DjPIkMkULgjtrWpPoCfDQiT9EmDpcnf2wnfYUgsIHFRtbNiUfpc\",\"nonce\":\"uUVlDiTXJ5jYEH92ePfkAxNeaUftWHB5\"}},\"addresses\":[\"4eaec019c6f1b6806426767b146bcbb4966d3608\"]}},\"encHdRootPriv\":{\"encStr\":\"zWNUrRZP2wJudMEqABB7sEl2lriDdAWyq0M0uZnKJUeQRe+rdDyIoUUQXADqk0gkSt4HCTVYIiC4kqtVREwbZS9hDwYl/UjQ0nckIeE71/pwbhk4VNstrGoiKBc48SJmiZ7PBpKK/nTqJ4DMuNylz4FhbtmHZmo0hwKxJVTXaQ==\",\"nonce\":\"WMsGPuaOQwF+b2m1tS1XvK/S8lquHCN0\"},\"salt\":\"sE1rr7QxQAA3RePjgfbWB5bg5fRInU+t5m1MBv5nsdc=\",\"version\":2}');
```

Answer (score 1):

I used regex to double up the single quotes:

```
yourstring = yourstring.replace(/'/g, "''")
```

[Regex for replacing a single-quote with two single-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609947/regex-for-replacing-a-single-quote-with-two-single-quotes)