# How to get rid of all apostrophes in a string python

Tags: python, parsing, python-requests

How do I get rid of all the apostrophes in this string:

```
text = "‘https://google.com/’"
```

I've tried this but it just returns the string with the first apostrophe gone and the end one stays and messes up my get request...

```
text = "‘https://google.com/’"
        if "'" in text:
            text = text.replace("'", '')
```

By the way, google.com is supposed to be replaced with a t.co link but stack doesn't allow it

Comment: Note that they aren't normal apostrophes. The open apostrophe and close apostrophe are different so you need to replace both.

Comment: A possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609947/regex-for-replacing-a-single-quote-with-two-single-quotes

Comment: Perhaps this is a silly question, but: can't you just...  Not type the apostrophes when you're creating your string literal to begin with? As in, `text = "https://google.com/"`. If you're thinking "in my actual code, the string isn't a literal. I get it from another process and I can't change how it's transmitted", it may be worthwhile to determine what format that process is using (e.g. JSON, etc), since there might be ready-made parsing solutions already. Saves you the effort of cleaning it yourself :-)

Answer (score 1):

They look the same, but not exactly the same characters. The first one is `\xe2\x80\x98` ([`LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128&utf8=string-literal)) while the second one is `\xe2\x80\x99` (`RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`).

Answer (score 1):

You list all your apostrophes in a regular expression and remove them:

```
import re
text = "‘https://google.com/’"
text = re.sub(r'[’‘]', '', text)
```

This will remove any `’` and `‘` in the text. If you want to remove additional types of characters, just modify the regexp to include them.

Comment: Okay, wasn't able to get it to work. Still only removes the first apostrophe... My program is scrapping a t.co link from a tweet that is posted from an iphone, does that make a difference with apostrophes?

Comment: The regexp in the example will remove any occurrences of  `’` and `‘` if they are in your text at all. Checked it and it's working. Run your Python script and try to understand how regular expressions work. Notice the difference between `'` and `’` and `‘` .